# Doubt about $K$-automorphisms of $K[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've seen that:
[image]

but... why the $K$-automorphisms of $K[x]$ are those maps?

Answer (score 1):

To see they are all of that form, if $\varphi$ is an automorphism and $\varphi(x) = y$, then every element of $K[x]$ can be written as

$$ c_0 + c_1 y + c_2 y^2 + c_3 y^3 + \ldots + c_n y^n $$

If $y$ is not linear, then contemplate how to write $x$ in the form above.

To see that they are all automorphisms, just write down the inverse transformation.